# alias command "date -d @" can not accept $1 on Mac

Tags: bash, date, alias

[the command in bash_profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmOAK.png)

`alias getTime1='date -d @1490170832 +"%F %H:%M:%S"'`

`alias getTime2='date -d @$1'`

[but in terminal it not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlfEt.png)

donaldlin@ ~ $ getTime1

2017-03-22 16:20:32

donaldlin@ ~ $ getTime2 1490170832

date: the argument ‘1490170832’ lacks a leading '+';
when using an option to specify date(s), any non-option
argument must be a format string beginning with '+'
Try 'date --help' for more information.

I have tried "date -d @\$1"，"date -d @'$1'"，"date -d ${@$1}" and so on, but it still not work.

update:
`alias`es can't take parameters. You need to create a function instead
Thanks @chepner and @l0b0

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't write your problem in the form of photos. Instead please write down (with appropriate formatting) the question. Also read this for how to ask a question here- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alias`es can't take parameters. You need to create a function instead.

Comment: I don't agree with you. I have try "cat $1" use alias. It is OK.

Comment: @donald: You probably defined your alias with double quotes, `alias foo="cat $1"`, which means `$1` expanded to an empty string and was discarded at the time of the definition. This means your alias is exactly the same as `alias foo=cat`. Aliases do *not* take arguments.

Comment: @chepner Oh, I see. Thank you very much. I try `alias foo1="cat $1,$2"` and `alias foo2="cat $2,$1`, and I get the answer.